# QVideoProbe, QML Camera, Android

Tags: android, qml, qt5

How QVideoProbe works?
For example, I changed QML Camera's (simply, camera) properties to `videoRecorder.videoCodec: "h264"` and `captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo`. Also I connected to camera's mediaObject with QVideoProbe and when `SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame))` will be emitted, I will recieve H.264 encoded QVideoFrame or raw QVideoFrame?

Comment: `pixelFormat()` can be used to check the format of the `QVideoFrame` inside the slot. If the format is not supported (e.g. YUV) you would read an `Format_Invalid` format.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo pixelFormat() returns `QVideoFrame::Format_NV21`. Does it mean, that QVideoFrame not encoded in H.264?

Comment: On Android video is encoded in YUV format, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21). You should convert that format to a Qt-compatible one for processing.

Comment: For example, I have frame in YUV format and then I can say, that is encoded frame? But what is H.264 encoder then? H.264 encoder developed for converting raw images to YUV (or other) format? Sorry, I'm not experienced in encode/decode/muxing of video.

Comment: I'm not expert either. I've just used `QVideoProbe` for my purposes but cannot really answer that part of the answer. Sorry. I guess so, but I can't say FIR dure. Msybe giving a look at the source may help.